# Trying to loop 3 threads in a specific order everytime

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

My question is how do I make a thread run, then after that another run, then after that another run again, then it repeats itself.

I have a main file

```
    private static ThreadManager threadManager;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    threadManager = new ThreadManager();
}
```

Then I have a ThreadManager class

```
public class ThreadManager {
 public static final Object lock1 = new Object();

public static ConcThread CT = new ConcThread();
public static SocketThread sThread = new SocketThread();
public static PacketThread packetThread = new PacketThread();

 public ThreadManager() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock1) {
            packetThread.packetThread.start();
                lock1.wait();
            CT.concThread.start();
                lock1.wait();
            sThread.socketThread.start();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Then I have 3 threads

```
        public class PacketThread implements Runnable {

        public Thread packetThread = new Thread(this);

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    synchronized (ThreadManager.lock1) {
                        //DoThing1
                        synchronized (this) {
                            ThreadManager.lock1.notifyAll();
                        }
                        ThreadManager.lock1.wait();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ConcThread implements Runnable {

    public Thread concThread = new Thread(this);

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (ThreadManager.lock1) {
                try {
                    //dothing2
                synchronized (this) {
                    ThreadManager.lock1.notifyAll();
                }
                ThreadManager.lock1.wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}

    public class SocketThread implements Runnable {

    public Thread socketThread = new Thread(this);

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (ThreadManager.lock1) {
                try {
                    //dothing3
                    synchronized (this) {
                        ThreadManager.lock1.notifyAll();
                    }
                    ThreadManager.lock1.wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to tell us in a more precise way what are you trying to accomplish, rather than force us to "reverse-engineering" your thoughts from your code?

Comment: Do you want your threads to wait for earlier threads to get completed? or do you simply want to fire three threads sequentially irrespective of outcomes of threads?

Comment: Is this C#?  I don't think C# has the "synchronized" or "implements" keywords...  This looks like Java...

Comment: Erm, Why would you want to? The whole point of threads is doing more than one thing at one time.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having a single lock shared between the three threads (which is in-determinant on which thread will pick up after a thread releases the lock), have three separate semaphore/locks, where thread #1 unlocks a semaphore for thread #2 after its task is complete, thread #2 unlocks the semaphore for thread #3, and thread #3 unlocks the semaphore for thread #1.

So it would look something like:

1. Thread #1 runs (thread #2 and thread #3 are currently blocked)
2. Thread #1 completes
3. Thread #1 unlocks semaphore for thread #2
4. Thread #1 blocks
5. Thread #2 runs
6. Thread #2 completes
7. Thread #2 unlocks semaphore for thread #3
8. Thread #2 blocks
9. Thread #3 runs
10. Thread #3 completes
11. Thread #3 unlocks semaphore for thread #1
12. Thread #3 blocks

Hope this helps,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at `Runnable` to identify the chunks of work you have, and an appropriate Executor to control what runs when?