# How can two threads accessing two methods of the same object one after another in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to loop 3 threads in a specific order everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447448/trying-to-loop-3-threads-in-a-specific-order-everytime)

I want to access two different methods of the same object from two threads one after another. Here is my code,

```
public class ThreadCoordination
{
private Thread threadSayHello;
private Thread threadSayWorld;
private boolean threadSayWorldStarted = false;

public ThreadCoordination()
{
    createThreads();
}

private void createThreads()
{
    threadSayWorld = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                // while (true)
                {
                    sayWorld();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {}
        }
    });

    threadSayHello = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                // while (true)
                {
                    sayHello();

                    if (!threadSayWorldStarted)
                    {
                        threadSayWorldStarted = true;
                        threadSayWorld.start();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {}
        }
    });

    threadSayHello.start();
}

private synchronized void sayHello() throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.print("Hello ");
}

private synchronized void sayWorld() throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println("World!");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new ThreadCoordination();
}
}
```

If i uncomment the call while(true), then I'll expecting the output like this,

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
...
```

Please guide me how do I do it.
Raja.

I don't know whether I can edit the closed post. I just want to post the solution as far as I know.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class SequenceAccess
{
private ReentrantLock myLock;
private Condition ensureSequence;
private int sequenceNo = 1;

public SequenceAccess()
{
    myLock = new ReentrantLock();
    ensureSequence = myLock.newCondition();

    startThreads();
}

private void startThreads()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                    method1();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {}
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                    method2();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {}
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                    method3();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {}
        }
    }).start();
}

private void method1() throws InterruptedException
{
    myLock.lock();
    try
    {
        while (sequenceNo != 1)
            ensureSequence.await();

        sequenceNo = 2;
        System.out.println("Method 1");
        ensureSequence.signalAll();
    }
    finally
    {
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}

private void method2() throws InterruptedException
{
    myLock.lock();
    try
    {
        while (sequenceNo != 2)
            ensureSequence.await();

        sequenceNo = 3;
        System.out.println("Method 2");
        ensureSequence.signalAll();
    }
    finally
    {
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}

private void method3() throws InterruptedException
{
    myLock.lock();
    try
    {
        while (sequenceNo != 3)
            ensureSequence.await();

        sequenceNo = 1;
        System.out.println("Method 3");
        ensureSequence.signalAll();
    }
    finally
    {
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new SequenceAccess();
}
}
```

Comment: lock object may help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain _why_ you want to do this?  The whole point of threads is asynchronous parallel operation.

Comment: IMHO, There no good/elegant/efficient way to do this because its a bad idea to use multiple threads to perform a task which would be done more simply and efficiently using one thread. I can think of lots of horrible ways to do this with multiple threads. ;)

Comment: I agree with Peter and Gray, but to play devil's advocate maybe this is a contrived example and the threads actually do more work (and that concurrently), but need to then synchronize for the tic-toc part, maybe offering their results. (But that would also be better handled by one thread looping with two sub-threads that he joins in a controlled fashion).

Comment: @Gray: I am new to Java. Just want to know whether it's possible and also it's legel.

Comment: it's possible. it's legal. it's pretty useless though. but variants on this get asked so much here it makes people cranky. is there some tutorial site that people are getting these questions from?

Comment: I want to execute the sayHello() followed by sayWorld(). I tried like this, threadSayHello.start(); threadSayWorld.start(); But it some times sayWorld() is called before sayHello(). To ensure the sequence, I did like this

Comment: @NathanHughes - I'm convinced that there is indeed some apalling book or website that contains gunge like this, but it's difficult to find it with Google.  There are so may really bad 'Introduction to Threads' sites that it's difficult to tell the rotten wheat from the useless chaff :(

Comment: @Raja the best answer is to do `while(true) { sayHello(); sayWorld(); }` This will ensure the sequence is correct with far less code.

Comment: @NathanHughes I thought of that, but how you serialise the code best depends on the use case. In this case, its best to use one thread.

Comment: @Peter : i couldn't agree more using 1 thread is best here. i don't know what you think i said. maybe you're referring to Thilo's comment?

Comment: Hi All, This is a very basic question, silly question, bad approach, etc.. But as a beginner I come across this question. I am refering Core Java Volume 1, 8th Edition By Cay Horstmann. While  reading about ReentrantLock, they saying that we can get more than 1 condition. I want to know this in a pratical situation. Thanks to all who spent ur valuable times for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM *does not guarantee order of thread execution*

In fact the JVM spec could be met entirely by running the hello thread until it terminates and then running the world thread until it terminates (with your program as written)

You will need to introduce some sort of token to be shared between the two threads and then have that token shuttled back and forth.

The token could be as simple as a Boolean which is true if hello has been output and false if world has been output.

Each thread will then have to spin (or wait for a condition - better performance with a condition) until the Boolean matches its expected state.

I recommend getting your hands on the most excellent "java concurrency in practice" book

Answer (score 0):

The task is indeed a bit strange because this is essentially a single-threaded task. Though, I know that applications may get very complicated and require many strange things, with multiple threads as well.

You can create two private objects of any type, e.g. `Object`, to be used as "events". Each thread's loop should `wait()` for one of the event objects, then perform its task (print the string), then `notify()` another event object, and then repeat the loop and `wait()` again. Another thread should do the same but with the event objects swapped.

Start both threads and then `notify()` the first event object. The action begins!